# XX, YY, ZZ circuit representations?

Tags: circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation

Is there a good primer or set of lectures\examples that show entirely how to take a given matrix and developing a circuit that represents it. I am trying to implement a program to find the lowest Eigenvalue - VQE approach - using quantum circuits. So far, what I have done, using tutorials I found, is as follows:

$H_{total} = H_1(\theta_1) + H_2(\theta_2) + H_3(\theta_3)$

I have been relying on simulating each term of the hamiltonian, the $H_i$, as separate circuits and measuring the expected values as $\theta_i$ changes.

However, as I have been told by my TA that one cannot simulate the hamiltonians separately to find the ground state.

Comment: Hi Enrique. How I understand VQE one doesn't need to evaluate the Hamiltonian H. One needs to represent H as a sum of Pauli terms and try to find the expectation values of each Pauli term without evaluation. Here is a link to my tutorial for VQE, where I didn't evaluate the Hamiltonian or a part of it.  

https://github.com/DavitKhach/quantum-algorithms-tutorials/blob/master/variational_quantum_eigensolver.ipynb

Comment: Hi, I actually followed your tutorials ! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I am actually a bit confused. I am wondering how I can in one circuit have the hamiltonian rather than what I am currently doing: creating two circuits, one representing XX + YY since they commute, and another representing ZZ?

Comment: One question do you want to find minimal eigenvalue of your presented $H_{total}$? If yes then why you are changing it with $\theta$s? I think $H_{total}$, in that case, shouldn't be changed

Comment: In VQE we are changing the prepared state. And we don't evaluate $XX$ or $YY$, we just measure the $\left\langle \psi \right| XX \left| \psi \right\rangle$, where $\psi$ is our prepared state. How calculate the $\left\langle \psi \right| XX \left| \psi \right\rangle$? We just simply measure what is the probability of measuring eigenvectors of $XX$ that have +1 eigenvalue ($\left| ++ \right\rangle$, $\left| -- \right\rangle$) and substarcting the probability of measuring eigenvectors of $XX$ that have -1 eigenvalue ($\left| +- \right\rangle$, $\left| -+ \right\rangle$).

Comment: I am still unsure about how develop Ansatz to be able to present the original hamiltonian - before decomposition.

Comment: Enrique did you see this presentation? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E947xs9-Mso
If not I highly recommend you to check it out, because there you can find an example of preparing ansatz(trial) state for two qubits and see how he deals with one of the Pauli terms from given Hamiltonian.

Comment: So just to be clear: if I wanted to simulate $e^{i Z_1 \otimes Z_2 }$ I would use the ansatz presented in the presentation and then the unitary for that Hamiltonian?

Comment: No, Firstly in VQE we don't want to simulate/evaluate anything. In VQE with ansatz circuit, we prepare a state $\psi$ and then we calculate the expectation values of Pauli products, which is done via measurement procedure and not via simulation or evaluation. Then we change the state to obtain different/more optimal state the will have better/smaller expectation value. The expectation value of some $P$ operator is given by this expression $\left\langle \psi \right| P \left| \psi \right\rangle$.

Comment: For example, if you have some arbitrary state $\psi = a \left| 00 \right\rangle + b \left| 01 \right\rangle + c \left| 10 \right\rangle + d \left| 11 \right\rangle$, then mathematically can be shown that $\left\langle \psi \right| P \left| \psi \right\rangle = \left|a\right|^2 - \left|b\right|^2 - \left|c\right|^2 + \left|d\right|^2$. So for estimating the expectation value in this case one only needs to find the probabilities of measuring $\left| 00 \right\rangle$, $\left| 01 \right\rangle$, $\left| 10 \right\rangle$ and $\left| 11 \right\rangle$ states.

Comment: And you don't need to simulate or evaluate the $ZZ$ product or $e^{Z_1 \otimes Z_2}$. In contrast, when you want to implement not VQE, but Quantum Phase Estimation algorithm (completely different algorithm), in that case, one should evaluate/simulate and worry about commuting operators.